# When does "though" act as an adverb?

Tags: adverbs

As I know, the word "*though*" doesn't need a comma before it (at the end of a sentence) if it's an adverb. How do I know if "*though*" is acting as an adverb? A few examples would be good! I've looked online and haven't found a single thing that tells me how to decide if "*though*" is an adverb.

Comment: It's easy to spot the difference between adverbial and prepositional "though". It is an adverb in the sense of "however" and it is often preceded by a comma (_It wasn’t very successful, though_; _He has got some good qualities, though_); elsewhere it’s a preposition, usually taking a clausal complement and alternating with "although" (_He couldn’t help us, though he certainly tried_; _Though it seems incredible, Ed actually passed his exams!_).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The OED provides quite a mouthful on *though* as an adverb. We can imagine the lecturer tapping his pointer on the chalkboard as he intones that *though* is:

> An adversative particle expressing that relation of two opposed facts or circumstances (actual or hypothetical) in which the one is inadequate to prevent the other, and therefore both concur, contrary to what might be expected.

Most important is that when *though* is used as an adverb, it modifies a verb. Whenever *though* is used to modify a verb and to talk about the opposite of what came before, or something different than what was expected, it's an adverb. In English, this often comes at the end of a sentence.

The OED also provides a list of meanings (or of words and phrases that can sometimes be substituted for *though* with the same sense):

- For all that
- in spite of that
- nevertheless
- howbeit
- however
- yet

If a sentence is composed like this, *though* is an adverb:

> I expected him to lose the election, though!

(Note that in the above, the sense is the same with or without a comma. The comma can be omitted to avoid interfering with the rhythm of the sentence, but it is not critical to the sense of the adverb.)

Try the substitutions yourself:

> - I expected him to lose the election, for all that!
> - I expected him to lose the election, nevertheless!

*Though* here tells us that the speaker either thought her candidate would lose when he won, or that he *did* lose but that the speaker's reaction is somehow apposite to what is or was expected of her. There are other possibilities as well, but the speaker's *expecting* is modified by the adverb *though.* Opposition, or a confounding of expectation, is what *though* expresses as an adverb.

If a sentence is composed like this, *though* is a *connective preposition:*

> - Though he tried, he lost.
> - He did his best to win, though he lost.

Here, *though* connects its clause to the main clause, and adds information to it, with the same sense of "notwithstanding" as in the adverbial use, but without acting to modify the action or effect of a verb, as an adverb does.

Comment: Please correct me on this: if "though" is used as an adverb

Comment: Please correct me on this: if "though" is used as an adverb, adding a comma before it won't make a difference, correct? But as a rule, if it is an adverb, don't add a comma before it, correct? Also, I clicked "enter" by accident.

Comment: I can't think of an instance when omitting the comma would change the meaning of _though._ As a "rule", though, I _do_ use the comma. It doesn't matter though.

Comment: Let me just ask one more question. It is stated that when "though" is used as an adverb, you don't use a comma before it, so why did you in your example, "I expected him to lose the election, though"?

Comment: It is not _required_ to use a comma before "though" as an adverb at the end of a sentence. Some do, and some don't. There is no **rule** governing the use of the comma. We use it, or do not, depending only upon our preference and the specific context.

Comment: What do you mean by "specific context"?

Comment: A native speaker might omit the comma in a given usage for reasons of rhythm. Context might dictate this, for instance when it's necessary to emphasize the word _though._ The important thing for you to remember is that the comma is not required by any "rule".

Answer (score 2):

*Though* is an adverb when it's used when you are saying something that contrasts from your previous statement

For example:

> It was hard work, but I enjoyed it though
>
> We didn't win, but our strategy was great though

Comment: But doesn't "though" in the example, "We didn't win, but our strategy was great, though," also be contrasting?

Comment: @Tim Yes..it's contrasting.. *didnt win* is a negative statement..and another statement was positive

Comment: You can check out what does it mean by though in **Merriam-Webster**

Comment: If it's contrasting, why was a comma used before "though"? You said that "though" is an adverb when it contrasts with what was said before, and if "though" is acting as an adverb, why did you use a comma before it?

Comment: @Tim Okay, I shall omit the comma. But there is no rule that says you can't use comma after "though"

Comment: Sorry, I supposed to write **before though**