# Though to select an option

Tags: prepositions, adverbs, conjunctions

I have read [this ELL question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/129962/using-though-in-the-middle-of-a-sentence) and [this ELL question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/107177/when-does-though-act-as-an-adverb) but isn't clear to me how the "though" word is used in this sentence. Is it used to show selection? (I say the blue one) or other meaning is applied?

> Which piece will be used for this experiment?
>
> Ideally both pieces would work, though blue if you only have time for one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*[Though](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/though)* in your example is used as a conjunction to mean *but*. The sentence means that ideally both pieces would work, but if you only have time for one choose the blue one.